# Need help deciphering writing on old headstone

Tags: translation

I cant seem to read exactly what this says. I am recreating a headstone that was originally made out of white marble in 1888. It has deteriorated badly. I have figured out everything except this last word.
The line begins with "Betet für die" and then this word pictured. I am reasonably sure that it begins with an uppercase S.I simply can't figure out what this poor woman wanted us to pray for!  Please help if possible - i'm at my wits end![image]

Entire stone photo included. The line i'm needing is the tiniest one at the bottom. I've deciphered all the rest of the stone and only need the very last word on it. [image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest the last word is

> Seelenruhe

that is "rest/silence of the soul".

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to: +1.

Comment: you are amazing!! Thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: I was in the process of looking for words containing "ruhe" as I touched on the whole peace and rest thing.

Comment: The total last line I guess reads "Betet für die Seelenruhe" although it looks more like "Hotel für die Seelenruhe" or "Hetzt für die Seelenruhe", but both of the latter don't really make sense to me.

Comment: @celtschk totally naming my next Hotel "Hotel für die Seelenruhe" :D